# scrolling up and down slowly with JQuery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have this code for scrolling up and down in Html :

```
<div id="Response" class="comment"></div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="but4 , text15"><a id="Resp" href="#rp">Answer</a></div>
```

and this code in Jquery :

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#Resp").click(function () {
        $("html").animate({ scrollTop: $("#Response").offset().top }, 1200);
    });
</script>
```

but it's not working .. how can I fix this ? I want when I click on answer it scroll to up and go to Response div .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using the ScrollTo plugin instead of rolling your own solution: http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html

Demo is here: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

You can easily specify duration: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/

**EDIT**

The solution we came up with in chat is this (not including`script` tags):

```
$(function () { 
    $("#Resp").click(function () { 
        $("body").scrollTo($("#Response"), 1200); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: I am not professional in Jquery . Can you provide me a code ?

Comment: Sure, I've added an example. But you have to add that scrollTo plugin to your project that I linked to.

Comment: I use this code now :     <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.scrollTo.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#Resp").click(function () {
            $.scrollTo($("#Response"), 1200);
        });
    </script>

Comment: Did yours work? If not, try my edit. Remember to wait for the DOM to be ready.

Comment: Not again . I'm using this now : <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.scrollTo.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             $.scrollTo($("#Response"), 1200);
         });
     </script>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13422/discussion-between-persian-and-simplecoder)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the browser implementation, but you can get it to work in webkit (safari, chrome) and firefox with

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#Response").offset().top }, 1200);
```

Comment: It works for me in Firefox and in Chrome (I'm using a fixed value for scrollTop). You're including jquery 1.5.1, latest version is 1.7.2 - if you can, you should update it.